# Import class from another file

Tags: python, import

I know this question has been asked before, but none of the given answers worked. Say I have a file named Test.py with this code:

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        print('Instance Created')
```

I want to use this class in another file, say Test2.py.
I used the path to the file to get the class, but the message `attempted relative import with no known parent package` pops up
.
I am using IDLE on Mac OS X.
The path to the file is `/Users/*name*/Desktop/Code/Test.py`, where `*name*` is my username for this device.
Code in Test2.py:

```
from .Users.*name*.Desktop.Code.Test import Test
```

When I run the program, this message comes up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/*name*/Desktop/Code/Test2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .Users.owen.Desktop.Code.Test import Test
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I have tried using sys.path.append but it doesn't seem to work. I have also tried using just `.Desktop` or `.Code` instead of the full name, but this gives the same error. I researched packages online, but am struggling to fully comprehend what they are, much less make/use them. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are both of your files in same directory

Comment: @Sachin Im not sure what a directory is, how to find out if my files are in the same one, or how to make one.

Comment: directory means, folder

Comment: how do I find which directory a file is in? Is it just the word just before it in the file name? If so then the files are in the same directory.